# Can anyone see what I did wrong with this Make Feature layer function? (Arcpy)

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop

So I am just testing this function by itself before I put it in my loop. So I run the test (Python 2.7) and I get a result saying that it was create, but I do not see it in folder I assigned it to. I even tried it on the arcpy box in arcgis 10.2 and I still can't find the layer. I double checked the path I directed it too but nothing.

```
    import arcpy
    import os        

    arcpy.env.workspace = 'C://Users/my/workspace/'
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    inPut = 'C://Users/my/workspace/'

    allStorms = 'allstorms.shp'

    acrpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (allstorms, inPut+'group1')
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish? How would you do it manually (e.g. through ArcMap, without using Python)?

Comment: I am trying to use the SelectLayerByAttribute function to add a selection on a layer. In my allstorms.shp, I am trying to the information in my field name (CONF) and separate it into 3 groups, >80, 60-69, <60. Now that I am explaining this to you, I think I have to make allstorms.shp into a layer because I don not think this attribute take shapefiles

Comment: Again, how would you do this manually? Is the desired end result a layer, layer file, feature class, shapefile, other? Please [edit your question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/89454/edit) to include all of the relevant information in your question rather than using the comments.

Comment: I would first go to the ArcToolbox, click on layers and Table Veiws, then select Select layer by Attribute. When the box pops up, under layer name I selected allStorms.shp, under selection I used NEW_SELECTION, and under Epression I used [CONF] >= 80.

Comment: I get this error when I do the function in saying 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("allActiveFire.shp","NEW_SELECTION"," CONF >= 79 ")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6688, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
The value cannot be a feature class
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Comment: "The value cannot be a feature class" -- that is the problem right there. You need to either refer to an existing layer in the map document, or create a new layer using MakeFeatureLayer_management before running SelectLayerByAttribute and reference the new feature layer by name.

Comment: I tried that too. the MakeFeatureLayer function says my layer is create but the layer doesn't show up in my file so I can then use the SelectLayerByAttribute function. I took aaron advice (down below) and first used the MakeFeatureLayer_management then arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management but the arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management says the layer does't not exist. I'll try it out again.

Comment: Just trust that it exists (temporarily, within the current Python/ArcMap session) and be sure to reference it in the SelectLayerByLocation command by the same name you give it in the MakeFeatureLayer command.

Comment: Does the same goes with the Python by itself? Because that it is what we are using.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking but I think the answer is yes :)

Answer (score 7):

Because `'group1'` is in memory, you would need to save it to a layer file if you want to visually confirm its existence.  One approach:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\my\workspace'
ws = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

allStorms = 'allstorms.shp'
acrpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (allstorms, 'group1')
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management ('group1', os.path.join(ws, 'group1' + '.lyr'))
```

Comment: would you have to do this when you are using the Select Layer By Attribute function afterwards. My main goal is to make new layer along with a field name and it's data that are greater than 80 from a previous shapefile. I use the ArcGIS resource center for references and their 2 examples uses the makeFeatureLayer_management and then the Select Layer By Attribute_management. I hope I make sense.

Comment: No, you do not need to create a layer file when using select layer by attributes.

Comment: Your explain makes more sense since you have to save the layer in order to use it but I am not sure why the example in the ArcGIS resource center does not use the SaveToLayerFile_management. Check it out: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000071000000

Comment: oh okay. I guess I will try it without creating a layer than. Thank for the help, now I know more about the make a feature layer.

Comment: You do not need to save a temporary layer (e.g. 'group1') as a layer file.  This is only done if you want to actually visualize the layer.  When you use `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()`, you are essentially creating a feature stored in your computer's memory rather than being saved to disk.  When you quit ArcGIS, the layers are automatically deleted until you create them again.  You can use these temporary layers (e.g. 'group1') as input for tools such as `SelectLayerByLocation_management ()`.